# How to find top 5 customers(with max orders) per country in Tableau?

Tags: dataset, tableau-api

How to find top 5 customers(with max orders) per country in Tableau?

I have dataset from Amazing Mart

Data:

```
| OrderId | Customer Name | Country
| 1       | ABC           | France
| 2       | XYZ           | United States
| 3       | LMN           | France
```

I want to find top N customers (by number of orders) for each country and represent that as Bar chart. I have tried RANK, INDEX, Filters but not able to get the data. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 3 approaches:

- Use a table calc like Rank() to compute the ranking on the client side, and include that table calc, or another one like Index() in a filter to hide the low ranked marks. You’ll need to understand how partitioning and addressing work with Table Calculation - see the Tableau help for explanation. This is pretty easy And flexible once you understand table calcs, but doesn’t scale to extremely large data sets because all the ranking and filtering is done client side, requiring you to fetch a lot of data from the data source that won’t even be displayed. Can be fine for modest sized data sets.
- Use a context filter to first filter to a single country at a time then use the Top tab on a second filter to Restrict to the Top 5 customers for the selected country. (Context filters are applied first, then the other filters, like the top 5 filter are applied) This is very easy, and efficient. You can show the country filter to allow people to interactively pick the country, but it only works with one country at a time.
- Use custom SQL or preprocessing to calculate ranks for each customer scoped by the country. Then use this new derived column to filter and order the data included  in the visualization. This can be efficient for very large data sets, but a bit more maintenance effort and bit less flexible (say if your criteria for grouping customers changes to region or province). One of the few reasons custom SQL is still useful with Tableau. SQL Analytic or windowing queries can be useful here - those using keywords like OVER or PARTITION BY.